# java if long does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, if-statement, long-integer

really strange situation I got here. I have 2 classes.

```
  
@Entity
public class CategoryData extends EntityData {
    public Long parentId;

    @Column(unique=true)
    public String name;
    public Picture picture;
}
```

```
  
@Entity
public class PropertyGroupData extends EntityData {
    public Long categoryId;
    public String adminDescription;
    public String title;
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public List properties = new LinkedList();

}
```

this is the entity class for my hibernate.

```
 
@MappedSuperclass
public class EntityData implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date created = new Date();
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date modified = new Date();

    public Long version =  0L;
    // W:waiting,A:active,D:deleted
    public Character status;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE);
        //return "EntityData[id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

here comes the situation. I got some data in my database and it works well. until now.

```
for(CategoryData c:kategoriler)
    if(pgd.categoryId.toString().equals(c.id.toString()))
        out.print("1-find equal "+c.id);
for(CategoryData c:kategoriler)
    if(pgd.categoryId==c.id)
        out.print("2-find equal "+c.id);
```

the first for loop works normally and prints 1-find equal 7 but second loop does not print anything. they both Long. what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expressions are of type `Long`, which is a class, and are therefore compared by *reference identity*. If they were `long`, it would be fine. Try this instead:

```
for(CategoryData c:kategoriler)
    if(pgd.categoryId.longValue() == c.id.longValue())
        out.print("2-find equal "+c.id);
```

Comment: Those primitive vs object values are causing much more issues than it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing 2 objects by reference. That is, you're checking whether they're references to the same object. What you want is to check if they have the same values, e.g.

```
if(pgd.categoryId.longValue() == c.id.longValue())
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Long overrides the .equals, you can use the .equals() method, just like you do with strings.

```
for(CategoryData c:kategoriler)
{
  if (pgd.categoryId.equals(c.id))
  {
      out.print("2-find equal "+c.id);
  }
}
```

Using the == just compares the object references.